# How to get a reference to an object in an array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of objects. I try to pass an object from the array to another controller and update it there.

```
let items: [XX] = [XX1, XX2]
```

The following line doesn't give a reference to that object. instead it is obviously copying it!

```
var item = items[0]
```

The following line fails to update the object in the array:

```
item.seen = true
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please mention the reason of the downvote?

Comment: `this has nothing to do with arrays`. Do you mean that the OP should know where is his problem before he asks the question? isn't that why he is asking in the first place? which may be also the case for others who also thinks that the array was the problem. and thats maybe why I didn't find the answer searching using the keywords that I thought caused the problem. which also maybe used by others.

Comment: `Also show real code, not snippets, as your testing procedure might be faulty` If the code added serves the purpose and its not faulty how would you know its 'maybe faulty`?

Comment: I am not sure about the rule here. but I think that a question that uses different keywords and has same answer as another question should stay. and it shouldn't be treated as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make it an array of `class` type , not `struct` type , then manipulating will be reflected to the original array